# Ruby pass arguments to a method

Tags: ruby

I would like to add a method to a class C

```
class C
end
```

I defined a proc:

```
impl = proc{|x,y| puts "x=#{x} - y=#{y}"}
```

I added the proc to the class as a method `foo`:

```
C.send(:define_method, :foo, lambda do |args = impl.parameters.map { |arg| arg[1] }|
        puts "foo is called"
        impl.call(args)
    end
 )
```

When I call `foo` as `C.new.foo(1,2)`, I get an error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
```

To avoid this, I need to call `foo` like `C.new.foo([1,2])`. Someone can tell me how to avoid this problem?

Comment: Huh? Could you not define a "normal" method?

Comment: Did you try C.new.foo(1,2) ?

Comment: Ah, of course. I need more coffee :) Still, my question stands, is this complexity warranted? With regular methods you wouldn't have any problems, just saying.

Comment: You'll have to explain, what it is that you're trying to do there. Especially in the `lambda do |args = impl.parameters.map { |arg| arg[1] }|`

Comment: Simpler code: https://pastebin.com/JzpQkaiu No signature checks. You're free to implement them in the method body, though.

Comment: Yes, i would like to use proc and not regular methods

Comment: Thanks, that works !

Comment: Well, you defined the method to take one optional parameter, and you call it with two arguments, so you naturally get an error. If you want to call it with two arguments, you need to define it with two parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question stated:

```
C.send(:define_method, :foo, lambda do |*args|
  args = impl.parameters.map(&:last) if args.empty?
  puts "foo is called, args are: #{args.inspect}"
  impl.call(*args)
end)
C.new.foo(1,2)
#⇒ foo is called, args are: [1, 2]
#  x=1 - y=2
```

Since you want to pass an arbitrary amount of parameters to the method, the `lambda` should receive splat argument.

Also, defaulting to `impl.parameters.map(&:last)` makes not much sense, since the defaults will be *symbols* `[:x, :y]`.